# Why can fetch send an ArrayBuffer but not XHR caanot?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I want to know why the fetch API can send an ArrayBuffer instance but the XMLHttpRequest API cannot. And why is it removed from XMLHttpRequest ?

I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: It appears it was a specification simplification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView  Rather than having a list of typed arrays you can send, they've grouped them all under "ArrayBufferView". You'd need at least a DataView to read the ArrayBuffer anyway, plus you can always get to the underlying ArrayBuffer if you really need to.

Comment: post this as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it was [a specification simplification](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView). Rather than having a list of typed arrays you can send, they've grouped them all under "ArrayBufferView". You'd need at least a DataView to read the ArrayBuffer anyway, plus you can always get to the underlying ArrayBuffer if you really need to.